# Is there a way to reference cells in a closed CSV file from an Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a folder with several hundred CSV files. They all have the same format of the same type of information.

I need a way to run a query on the data in each of the CSV's and not have to open all of them.

The formula that I need to run against each CSV is this:

```excel-formula
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((F2:F1000=FALSE)*(F2:F1000<>""),C2:C1000,""))
```

This will pull in the data that I need.

What I have tried, unsuccessfully, so far:

```excel-formula
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((CONCAT("'FILE\PATH\[",FILENAME,"]SHEETNAME'!F2:F1000)=FALSE)*(CONCAT("'FILE\PATH\[",FILENAME,"]SHEETNAME'!F2:F1000")<>""),CONCAT("'FILE\PATH\[",FILENAME,"]SHEETNAME'!C2:C1000"),""))
```

The *FILENAME* is coming from a list in column A of the workbook that I am working in.

Is there a way to run this formula against each CSV without having to open them?

Comment: No, the only way to use a concatenate string as a true reference is with INDIRECT().  INDIRECT is Volatile and as such requires that the target file be open.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for the quick response. That's not the answer I was hoping for, but it's what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Craner is correct. There is no way to reference a range in a closed workbook.

The solution ended up being:

1. Enter Formula in working workbook
2. Open other workbooks (in groups of about 10 at a time)
3. Close other workbooks
4. Formula gathered the data that I needed while the other workbooks were open

Thankfully this was a one time process of gathering data.